# MyPy / python type hints doesn't catch called function that can return multiple types

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

The [attrgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) function can return different types based on the arguments you give it. If you pass an iterable with one item, it will return simply the given field of an object; if you pass it an iterable with multiple items, it returns a tuple of these fields of an object.

However, when using type hints + MyPy, this discrepancy is not picked up by MyPy (it throws no errors):

```
from operator import attrgetter


class OneThing:
    foobar = "hello"
    fields = ['foobar']


class TwoThings:
    foobar = "hello"
    goodbye = "potatoes"
    fields = ['foobar', 'goodbye']


def attrgettertest(thing) -> tuple:
    return attrgetter(*thing.fields)(thing)


def main():
    onething = OneThing()
    twothings = TwoThings()

    t1 = attrgettertest(onething)
    t2 = attrgettertest(twothings)

    print("Attrgettertest on 'onething' returned  {} with type {}".format(
        t1, type(t1)))
    print("Attrgettertest on 'twothings' returned  {} with type {}".format(
        t2, type(t2)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the output:

```
$ python attrgettrtest.py 
Attrgettertest on 'onething' returned  hello with type <class 'str'>
Attrgettertest on 'twothings' returned  ('hello', 'potatoes') with type <class 'tuple'>
$ mypy attrgettrtest.py 
$
```

The expected result would be something like this:

```
import random    

def test() -> tuple:
    if random.choice([0, 1]):
        return ("foo", "bar")
    return "foo"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for n in range(20):
        print(test())

$ mypy test.py 
test.py:8: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected Tuple[Any, ...])
```

Is this a bug in MyPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue here is that attrgetter has return type `Any`, and mypy doesn't catch this.

I posted this to the mypy repo and got the following [answer](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2884#issuecomment-281190150):

> I think the problem is that attrgetter has return type `Any`, so that your code passes. In principle, precise type checking would be difficult in such cases, however, there is a newly added flag `--warn-return-any` that will issue warnings in such situations (it will be available in 0.480, see PR [#2854](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/2854) for details).